# How do you go about reaching the Far Realm?

Tags: dnd-5e, dungeons-and-dragons, lore, planes

How do you go about reaching the Far Realm?

I appreciate the lore found in 5e so far about the Far Realm:

[Is there any official lore on the Far Realm?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/146927/is-there-any-official-lore-on-the-far-realm)

[What are all the creatures related to the Far Realm that have stat blocks in 5e?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/163481/what-are-all-the-creatures-related-to-the-far-realm-that-have-stat-blocks-in-5e)

**Is there any further lore on how to actually reach the Far Realm in the materials from 5e or previous editions?**

I know it is meant to be mysterious and mind-breaking place, but I wondered if there is any further information on ways of getting there. Or, further information about *Firestorm Peak* or the home world of the ancient elves who opened a portal to the Far Realm.

> The Far Realm has no well-known portals, or at least none that are still viable. Ancient elves once opened a vast portal to the Far Realm within a mountain called Firestorm Peak, but their civilization imploded in bloody terror and the portal’s location—even its home world—is long forgotten. Lost portals might still exist, marked by an alien magic that mutates the area around them.
>
> (DMG p.68)

If there is none, the proposal would be to go on an Inquisition spree with *Zone of Truth* and a liguist who knows *Deep Speech*, to find out exacly what the Aboleths, Beholders, Mind Flayers and Star Spawn know.

Comment: It may assist you to know that the Gates of Firestorm Peak was a 2e module - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Gates_of_Firestorm_Peak

Comment: What's more reputable than an official module? What source are you looking for?

Comment: @Nautarch - It's about knowing wether there are other modules or further sources. There might not be any more, but that is what I'd like to know if posssible.

Comment: Ah, that's fair. You're looking for more answers, not answers from more reputable sources.

Comment: :) yes, it didn't give me that option - maybe I should have chosen "draw attention"instead. I didn't know what to choose tbh. @NautArch

Comment: Amusing side note I've found: The Alienist Prestige class for 3.5 - which is a heavily Far Realm flavoured class - gains the ability Timeless Body at 9th level. A pretty standard No-aging feature alot of PrCs got. Only this one has an addition tagged onto the end of it's description: "An alienist is stolen away by horrible entities when her time is up, and she is never seen again." So this does answer your question, but it's usefulness is debatable.

Comment: I've taken off the portals tag as it isn't relevant here. OP is only looking for how to get there, not specifically using portals to get there.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

#### Location of the Vast Gate

Far Realm was initially created by Bruce Cordell for the AD&D 2e module *The Gates of Firestorm Peak*. This module is dated 1996, so you cannot find any lore from, say, Planescape series of products. In the module, we learn that some long time ago, a so called "Vast Gate" was opened by Elder Elves and then had to be sealed, yet the sealing was imperfect and was re-opening periodically under certain conditions and the players try to close it completely.

The setting is described to be located near the Firestorm Peak, in "the Shirelands, at the southern foothills of the Mountains of Frost". **Such a location is not defined in any of the official campaign settings of D&D**. Cordell penned a number of different products at the time and these products occasionally refer to the same locations or people (forming something like a Cordell-verse), but each of these products were meant to be easily integrable to any campaign setting, so we really don't know when and where the Vast Gate was first opened within the D&D multiverse.

On the other hand, a number of people have compared some of Cordell's later work, which takes place in Greyhawk (3e's default setting), with the Cordell-verse generic products and concluded that there are both for and against arguments for integrating the Vast Gate into the history of Oerth. An example proposal that discusses the available data can be found on a [2010 post](https://mimir.planewalker.com/forum/so-when-exactly-was-lawchaos-war?page=1) by user ripvanwormer on planewalker.com. Taking into account the date when the elves first came to Toril, he proposes that the Vast Gate could have played a role in that migration and hence considers sometime in the middle of -30,000 to -18,000 DR to be reasonable time for the accidental first contact of the Elder Elves with the Far Realm.

#### After the Closing of the Vast Gate

The Vast Gate is revisited in Cordell's article "Enter the Far Realm" published in [Dragon magazine #330](https://archive.org/stream/DragonMagazine260_201801/DragonMagazine330#page/n13/mode/2up) (2005). At this point it is described to be no longer open. Yet **occasional contacts with the Far Realm are said to happen at random locations**, causing so-called "cerebratic blots" to appear in the Prime Material Plane and allowing travel. Yet again, no mention of any of the official D&D campaign settings is made, except for Eberron.

Likewise, if we look at the discussion in the 3e *Manual of Planes*:

> **There are no known portals to the Far Realm**, or at least none that are still viable. Ancient elves once pierced the boundary of eons with a vast portal to the Far Realm, but their civilization imploded in bloody terror and the portal's location is long-forgotten. But other portals might exist. 
>   **Other methods of reaching the Far Realm include traveling to time's beginning or end or finding the true Dreamheart past the Portal of Sleep.**

The 4e *Manual of Planes* does not contradict with this description, mentioning that it only touches rarely the material world and that it is not normally a place one can visit.

#### Novels - Living Gate

This lore is somewhat contradicted by the Forgotten Realms short story *Watchers at the Living Gate* by Paul Park published in the D&D anthology *Untold Adventures*. It describes the so-called Living Gate, **a tiny portal located in the Feydark**, beneath the ruined eladrin metropolis of Cendriane. Cendriane was mentioned in the 4e *Manual of Planes*, but to the extent that I could track, the Living Gate was not mentioned anywhere beyond the short story.

#### Eberron Specific

Finally, if you are playing in the Eberron campaign setting, the Far Realm is incorporated as the Realm of Xoriat in Cordell's above mentioned Dragon article. Yet, please note that Eberron [exists in its own micro-cosmology](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KvGkY3JiIsM&t=451), so it is up to the DM how to interpret the Far Realm - Xoriat correspondence. [There has been a motto that everything that is in D&D is in Eberron but not possibly in a form you recognize.]

Comment: Was there not some lore in 4e that said the heart of most stars were gateways to the Far Realm? I seem to recall that, but am having trouble finding it. If so that would be a lot of portals on the Material Plane abet hard to actually enter.

Comment: @L.P.: I am afraid my 4e knowledge is the weakest, so I cannot really confirm or refute your point.

Comment: Thank you so much for so informative and full answer!

Comment: @L.P.  Hi - if you find the source of that gateway, please share it. :)

Comment: @Orc's Plunder Ah found it. Slight mis-remember, slight vague description. Under 4e's Star Pact Warlock it briefly mentions how Warlocks achieve power by tapping into Far Realm beings "Related to stars." Dragon #366 goes only into slightly more detail with this. So to clarify: It heavily implies Stars are related to powerful Far Realm beings, but never actually states what the relationship is.

Comment: @ZwiQ Do you think the new content in Tasha's Cauldron of Everything (pp. 152-153) about the Far Realm may provide another viable way to travel to the Far Realm?

Comment: @Orc'sPlunder: If I understand correctly, Tasha's talks about regions that are influenced by the Far Realm, but does not explicitly talk about permanent portals. If the DM desires, a rift that opens in such a region might be used. Do you have anything in particular to add to the answer?

Comment: @ZwiQ Hi there, sorry for delay. Yes, there is a bit on the d100 roll (96-00) page153 which refers to creating a rift that passes through the Far Realm - could a PC potentially use this to travel to the Far Realm and stay? Just curious.

Comment: Xoriat fills some similar narrative roles as the Far Realm, somewhat, but it really isn’t actually the Far Realm per se.

Comment: @L.P. You should turn that into an answer and collect some well-earned upvotes.

Comment: @Thank-Glob I don't see any way to go through the resulting portal, without also 'instantly' ending up on the random destination plane (which is presumably *not* a Far Realm plane; GM's choice)... However, it appears the 9th Level spell *Gate*, would let you *return* to the Far Realm plane you passed through; & of course *Wish* could do the same (without having to "produce any effect other than duplicating another spell", for once). Plane Shift would need a forked metal rod that's somehow been attuned to that plane, but otherwise it could get you there, too!?

Answer (score 13):

### The [Rrakkma](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/248633/DDIAMORD-Rrakkma-5e) adventure module includes a portal to the Far Realm

This adventure module for Adventurer's League includes a portal to the Far Realm, although it's up to you how "canon" you consider this.

In "Area 11. The Cathedral" of "Section 2. Temple of Madness", which is on the plane of [Pandemonium](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Pandemonium):

> This cathedral must have been something to behold at one point in time, but now the porous stone and winds of Pandemonium have brought it to its current decrepit state. At the far end of the cathedral is a shining adamantine archway alight with runes of power. The gate to the Far Realm is open. Due to some strange influence of the Far Realm, the winds of Pandemonium do not touch this place at the moment.
>
> *— Other Features, Area 11. The Cathedral, p. 14*.

Section 3 is then set in the [Far Realm](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Far_Realm), although it's only two pages (pp. 15-16) and it doesn't really go into that much detail. A couple of interesting descriptions are:

> Experiencing the Far Realm is not for the weak of mind. EVERY round the adventurers are in the Far Realm, they must each make a successful DC 15 Wisdom saving throw at the beginning of each turn or suffer the effects of *confusion* that round. The chart has been modified from the one in the *Player’s Handbook* to more accurately reflect the effects of the Far Realm. Please use this one.
>
> *— Far Realm Confusion, p. 15*.

> Even saying the word ‘exploration’ in the Far Realm can be a harrowing experience. Focusing on a single objective really is the key to maintaining sanity.
>
> Nonetheless should an adventurer do so, the experience is so disorienting (filled with images of tentacles, eyeballs, and mouths), they need to make a successful DC 15 Intelligence saving throw or be Stunned until the beginning of their next turn.
>
> *— Exploration, Playing the Pillars, p. 16*.

It also includes the information on the Far Realm from the DMG (p. 68) as a side bar on p. 15.

Comment: For those that don't have access to the links, what edition is the module from? Is it a sub module from a certain season or book?

Comment: @Eternallord66 I believe anything Adventurer's League must be 5e, since they only run AL for 5e, and I don't believe it's from any specific season (like how the current season is for Descent Into Avernus, for example), I think it's effectively a standalone module. It's "code" is DDIAMORD, where MORD I assume means Mordenkainen's Tome of Foes, so I assume it was basically a "tie-in" just to promote that book.

Comment: I looked into it and it was a standalone adventure to introduce MToF.

Comment: Also, given the nature of the Far Realm, it would not be unreasonable to suggest that concepts such as "a reliable method of travel" may not even apply, or may not work according to any logic we might be able to bring to bear. That's a Multiverse way of thinking, and may be as relevant to the Far Realm as the concept of "up" is to a strictly 2-dimensional being-- it just can't be understood or even represented in that frame of reference. This is obviously a DM decision, but is another way the question might be addressed.

Comment: @Upper_Case That's a *really* good point: In older editions, crystal spheres kept the phlogiston out & the gods in; If I recall correctly, characters outside in the phlogiston could cut off from their gods? (So, no magic!?!?) The Far Realm was stated to emit harmful effects and entities which even the gods abhorred, hence... barriers. Pretty good chance any given plane might have a deity blocking such portals, & who says the Far Realm planes in question, are accepting incoming gate spells anyway?  ;D

Answer (score 0):

### Plane Shift might work

This answer is not providing additional lore, but a rules-consistent way how to reach the Far Realm that does not need additional lore.

The Far Realm section in the DMG is a subsection of the "**Other Planes**" section that starts on page 67, next to the Outlands with Sigil and Demiplanes, indicating that it might be  considered as a plane, if one outside of the known multiverse.

You can [plane shift to a Demiplane](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/79645/can-you-plane-shift-to-a-pocket-dimension), so it stands to reason you should be able to plane shift to the Far Realm. [Illustro points out](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/165009/how-do-you-go-about-reaching-the-far-realm#comment549134_201193) that you would need a forked metal rod attuned to the Far Realm to make this work, and that may be hard to come by. The kind of aberration probing you point at may be required as part of the research to get there.

Wether allowing that as a DM is wise is another question. The intent of the Far Realm seems to pretty clearly be a place of unspeakable horrors warping the mind and substance of reality, to be used as a narrative plot device and to be avoided and cut off by the characters, not as a plane to be adventured in; once you can look at and explore horror, it stops being horror.

The proposal to extract knowledge out of mind-flayers and aboleths might be a rational, scientific way to try and do that, and I feel the appropriate response by the DM to such tactics should be a "science gone wrong" one, where the characters or factions doing so bring doom and madness upon themselves.

Comment: Plane shift requires a forked metal rod attuned to the relevant plane of existence you are shifting too. Getting such a tuning fork for the Far Realm may be *ahem* "difficult"

Comment: @illustro: granted. And if you had one, I think using it would be most ill-advised.